# Laravel | Query with select

Tags: laravel, controller

I have a query and use ->pluck and i see my result

[22]

```
$ferias = feria::where('id_funcionario', '=', $userid)->pluck('n_ferias_disponiveis');
```

I can see my result without [] ?
For exemple use de select 'n_ferias_disponiveis', but how do you use select in the above query?

Comment: if you are looking for id and n_ferias_disponiveis then ->pluck('n_ferias_disponiveis','id_funcionario'); .Also note only two columns can select in pluck query not mroe than tht

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ferias = Feria::select('id_funcionario')->where('id_funcionario', '=', $userid)->get();
```

Pluck is collection function you should first get then you can use pluck method like:

```
$ferias = Feria::select('id_funcionario')->where('id_funcionario', '=', $userid)->get()->pluck('id_funcionario');
```